# In camel route, code control not able to go inside process() method

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to consume Kafka messages using camel.

The below code:

```
public class Main {

private static CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        context.start();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                System.out.println("Configuring Routes");

                from("kafka:172.16.30.5:9093?topic=reddy&groupId=testing&autoOffsetReset=earliest&consumersCount=1")                
                .process(new Processor(){

                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {


                        /*System.out.println("Processing..");
                        System.out.println("Messages:");
                        System.out.println(exchange.getIn());*/

                        String messageKey = "";
                        if (exchange.getIn() != null) {
                            Message message = exchange.getIn();
                            Integer partitionId = (Integer) message
                                    .getHeader(KafkaConstants.PARTITION);
                            String topicName = (String) message
                                    .getHeader(KafkaConstants.TOPIC);
                            if (message.getHeader(KafkaConstants.KEY) != null)
                                messageKey = (String) message
                                        .getHeader(KafkaConstants.KEY);
                            Object data = message.getBody();


                            System.out.println("topicName :: "
                                    + topicName + " partitionId :: "
                                    + partitionId + " messageKey :: "
                                    + messageKey + " message :: "
                                    + data + "\n");
                        }

                        }

                });

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
java -jar camelKafka-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger     (org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Configuring Routes
```

That is, the code control is not going into process method at all.

Comment: If you add a log() after the from but before the process() is that being logged?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep Camel running, see this documentation: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: This document is useful, when i tried to use camel for say transfering files from one location to another...but did not help me in kafka consumption of messages. somehow still the code controll is not going inside the process()!!Any idea??